# Como fazer download de um arquivo .pdf com JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

Estou utilizando JSF e Primefaces, e preciso fazer download de um PDF que gerei com o iReports e o Jasper.

Eu salvo o PDF dessa forma, nesse caminho:

```
String caminhoReports = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/reports");

File pdf = new File(caminhoReports+"/relatorio2.pdf");
            pdf.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream arquivo = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(impressoraJasper, arquivo);
```

Ele fica salvo nesse diretório:

```
D:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\monitorias\WEB-INF\reports\relatorio2.pdf
```

Como faço para colocar um botão que faça download desse relatorio? Tentei utilizar o componente download do primefaces mas não deu, quando eu passo esse caminho ele diz que o resource não é válido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em um botão chame o método abaixo.

```java
// Aplicável ao JSF 2.x
private static final String PDF_URL = "http://.../file.pdf";

public void download() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    response.reset();   // Algum filtro pode ter configurado alguns cabeçalhos no buffer de antemão. Queremos livrar-se deles, senão ele pode colidir.
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");  // Define apenas o tipo de conteúdo, Utilize se necessário ServletContext#getMimeType() para detecção automática com base em nome de arquivo. 
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    // Lê o conteúdo do PDF
    URL url = new URL(PDF_URL);
    InputStream pdfInputStream = url.openStream();

    // Lê o conteúdo do PDF e grava para saída
    byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = pdfInputStream.read(bytesBuffer)) > 0) {
        responseOutputStream.write(bytesBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }    
    responseOutputStream.flush();

    // Fecha os streams
    pdfInputStream.close();
    responseOutputStream.close();         
    facesContext.responseComplete();         
}
```

Certifique-se que esse método não seja chamado por um pedido Ajax. Se você estiver usando a biblioteca [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/), poderá ser usado um dos métodos [`Faces#sendfile`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#sendFile-java.io.File-boolean-) para baixar um arquivo.

```java
public void download() throws IOException {
    Faces.sendFile(file, true);
}
```

Referências [Fonte¹](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394237/1608936), [Fonte²](http://www.itcuties.com/j2ee/jsf-2-download-file/)

Comment: Pode parecer besta. Mas como eu escrevo o InputStream para OutputStream?

Comment: @JoãoNeto Editei a resposta, veja se dá certo para você.

Comment: deu certo sim! Mas após essa forma consegui fazer também usando o componente do primefaces. Vou postar minha solução também.

Comment: @JoãoNeto Que bom que deu certo. Se puder marque a resposta como aceita. =)

Comment: Tinha esquecido desse detalhe kkk. =)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui a solução com a primeira solução da resposta do QMechanic73, mas logo após tambem consegui fazer utilizando o componente FileDownload do PrimeFaces:

**No meu .xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="Download do Edital" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
     <p:fileDownload value="#{editalBean.file}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

**No meu managedBean**

```
private StreamedContent file;

public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

public StreamedContent getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {

        String caminhoWebInf = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(caminhoWebInf+editalSelecionado.getSrcPDF()); //Caminho onde está salvo o arquivo.
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", "edital.pdf");  

        return file;  
    }
```